# Bootstrap/JQuery Responsive/Centered Modal w/ Google Docs IFRAME

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, responsive-design, bootstrap-modal

After days of trying variation after variation, I finally got all of the sizing parameters working, using default settings for the IFRAME to calculate default settings for everything else up to the screen size.  I then used this ratio to test against the actual screen size and reversed the entire process to build the actual widths and heights.

This new version works great, until applying vertical centering to the modal when it's sizes are dictated by the width.  Here's the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gu8dqdco/1/

All the resizing works perfectly if I don't calculate the margin-top in the ELSE statement:

```
if((windowX / windowY) > (defaultScreenWidth / defaultScreenHeight))
{
 modalY = windowY - (outerModalPadding * 2);
 modalX = (modalY * defaultModalWidth) / defaultModalHeight;
 modalMarginTop = outerModalPadding;
 modalMarginLeft = (windowX - modalX) / 2;
}
else
{
 modalX = windowX - (outerModalPadding * 2);
 modalY = (modalX * defaultModalHeight) / defaultModalWidth;
 modalMarginTop = (windowY - modalY) / 2;
 modalMarginLeft = outerModalPadding;
}
```

It isn't that it doesn't center the content, it's that the content shrinks when the width is adjusted as the controlling factor in all the sizing.

At this point, I'm out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Original:

> Alright, so, long story short: I've written a function that will center a modal and retain responsiveness while adding responsiveness to an IFRAME within the body of the modal.  I've tried to keep it universal for IFRAMEs while adding functionality for removing (hiding) the .controlbar of the Google Docs Viewer.  Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2n8cnnm/2/

Here's the function:

```
 function resizeModal() {
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
  var windowX = $(window).width();
  var windowY = $(window).height();
  var modal = $(this).find('.modal-dialog');
  var header = $(this).find('.modal-header');
  var headerY = header.height() + parseInt(header.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(header.css('padding-bottom')) + parseInt(header.css('border-top')) + parseInt(header.css('border-bottom'));
  var content = $(this).find('iframe');
  var contentX = parseInt(content.css('width'));
  var contentY = parseInt(content.css('height'));
  var body = $(this).find('.modal-body');
  var bodyPX = parseInt(body.css('padding-left')) + parseInt(body.css('padding-right'));
  var bodyPY = parseInt(body.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(body.css('padding-bottom'));
  if(((windowX) / (windowY)) > (contentX / contentY)) {
   var bodyY = windowY - headerY - bodyPX;
   var bodyX = (bodyY * contentX) / contentY;
  } else {
   var bodyX = windowX - bodyPY;
   var bodyY = (bodyX * contentY) / contentX;
  }
  var contentX = bodyX;
  var contentY = bodyY;
  var centerX = (windowX - bodyX) / 2;
  var centerY = (windowY - headerY - bodyY) / 2;
  modal.css('width', bodyX);
  body.css('width', bodyX);
  body.css('height', bodyY);
  content.css('width', contentX);
  content.css('height', contentY);
  var centerX = (windowX - bodyX) / 2;
  var centerY = (windowY - headerY - bodyY) / 2;
  modal.css('margin-top', centerY);
  modal.css('margin-left', centerX);
 }
```

So, I've got two issues.  First, the .modal-body width is sizing 30px too small.  I've fixed this by making "var contentX = bodyX - bodyPX;", but it causes problems with the resizing where for every resize it gets smaller and smaller.  Any ideas on how I can fix the width of the content without changing the body and causing this constant shrink?

The second problem is in regards to the ratio and its changeover from sizing off the height to sizing off the width.  If works great, to a point.  Resizing from a row-view to a column-view, it glitches and switches to sizing by width too early, forcing the top and bottom of the modal to appear off screen.  I know the windowX / windowY ratio isn't the ideal ratio to work with, but since the size of the modal, which I believe is the ideal ratio, is set by calculations done during the IF statement, I'm not entirely sure on how I can fix this.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated, and I'm sorry for the messy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At long last, I believe I found the solution, though it's not what I was hoping for.

It turns out the issue is with the definition of the `outerModalPadding` variable.  Previously, I had it set to pull the value from the CSS, which worked great, until the width of the page fell below 768px.  I tried to simply remove the resolution constraint on the CSS that defined this value, but that made no difference.

In the end, I just defined the fixed value in the jQuery.

Here's the working function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('iframe').each(function() {
  if($(this).hasClass('google')) {
   $(this).wrap('<div class="googleDIV"></div>');
  }
 });
 function resizeModal() {
  $(this).css('display', 'block');
  var modal = $(this).find('.modal-dialog');
  var header = $(this).find('.modal-header');
  var content = $(this).find('iframe');
  var modalBody = $(this).find('.modal-body');

  var outerModalPadding = 10;
  var innerModalPadding = 15;
  var defaultContentWidth = 600;
  var defaultContentHeight = 768;
  var googleControlbarHeight = 37;
  var defaultBodyWidth = defaultContentWidth + (innerModalPadding * 2)
  var defaultBodyHeight = defaultContentHeight - googleControlbarHeight + (innerModalPadding * 2);
  var headerY = header.height() + (innerModalPadding * 2) + parseInt(header.css('border-top')) + parseInt(header.css('border-bottom'));
  var defaultModalWidth = defaultBodyWidth;
  var defaultModalHeight = headerY + defaultBodyHeight;
  var defaultScreenWidth = defaultModalWidth + (outerModalPadding * 2);
  var defaultScreenHeight = defaultModalHeight + (outerModalPadding * 2);

  var windowX = $(window).width();
  var windowY = $(window).height();
  var bodyPX = parseInt(modalBody.css('padding-left')) + parseInt(modalBody.css('padding-right'));
  var bodyPY = parseInt(modalBody.css('padding-top')) + parseInt(modalBody.css('padding-bottom'));

  if((windowX / windowY) > (defaultScreenWidth / defaultScreenHeight))
  {
   modalY = windowY - (outerModalPadding * 2);
   modalX = (modalY * defaultModalWidth) / defaultModalHeight;
   modalMarginTop = outerModalPadding;
   modalMarginLeft = (windowX - modalX) / 2;
  }
  else
  {
   modalX = windowX - (outerModalPadding * 2);
   modalY = (modalX * defaultModalHeight) / defaultModalWidth;
   modalMarginTop = (windowY - modalY) / 2;
   modalMarginLeft = outerModalPadding;
  }
  bodyY = modalY - headerY;
  bodyX = modalX;
  contentY = bodyY + googleControlbarHeight - (innerModalPadding * 2);
  contentX = bodyX - (innerModalPadding * 2);

  content.css({width: contentX, height: contentY});
  modalBody.css({width: bodyX, height: bodyY});
  modal.css({width: modalX, height: modalY, 'margin-top': modalMarginTop, 'margin-left': modalMarginLeft});
 }
 $('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', resizeModal);
 $(window).resize(function resize() {
  $('.modal:visible').each(resizeModal);
 });
});
```

It can be found working at: http://jsfiddle.net/gu8dqdco/3/

If I find myself feeling the urge to do so, I'll revamp it so the Google controlbar removal is optional, likely through another class, but that's for another day.